# A valid license configuration is required error in Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I am building an AR application using Unity and Vuforia. I was able to build and run the application for testing on an android phone. It was working fine until I rebuild the app and then got an the following error about the license:
I keep getting the following error on an andriod phone after building and running application:

```
Vuforia Initialization Error 
LICENSE ERROR
A valid license configuration is required
```

I find this very weird as I didn't make any changes between the builds, so I am not sure what could have triggered this error.

I have have tried to delete the app on the phone and rebuild it multiple times. I have also tried closing and reopening unity, also restarting the phone. I have also tried to create a new license key and using the new key in the unity project. Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error no matter what I try. I have also scoured the internet but could find any solutions. The closest things I found was someone having a similar issue but with ios: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/archive-archive/ios/vuforia-engine-initialization-error-not-first-time
However, it is claimed that this issue is closed and fixed with version 9.2.8. but I am using a newer version of Vuforia 10.13.3.